# Reset exponential Schedule when combining retry and repeat in a ZIO loop

Tags: scala, zio

I am combining ZIO retry and repeat in a long polling procedure:
`logic.repeat(repeatSchedule).retry(retrySchedule)`
where logic is a ZIO that can fail.

Since `retrySchedule` can an exponential backoff it can grow indefinitely upon errors, however, I would like to reset it to its initial value upon the success of logic (which will be repeated infinitely)

I'm following the section about `Schedule` composition in [ZIO Scheduling doc](https://zio.dev/docs/usecases/usecases_scheduling) but I miss a "recursive" combination, in which something like the following is possible:

```
Schedule.exponential(baseDelay)
.whileOutput(_ < UpdaterManagerSettings.maxDelay)
.andThen([SOMETHING TO POINT RECURSIVELY AT THE SAME])
```

Comment: So you'd like to repeat `logic` every, let's say, 1 second as long as it succeeds. Then, when it fails, you'd like to retry it after 1, 2, 4 etc. seconds until it succeeds. Then, when it finally succeeds, you'd like to go back to repeating it every 1 second. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. 
Let's say that my logic performs an HTTP request to some server (which is actually the case). If the server is unreachable it's correct to increase the retry delay to give more time to the server to be on, but once it's back online, the program will repeat and it doesn't make any sense that another network issue in the far future will inherit the delay of the previous ones.

Comment: Does the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this may work for you:

```scala
val logic = ZIO(???)

// First, create an effect that uses exponential backoff to retry logic.
// This effect will complete as soon as logic succeeds,
// or maximum number of retries is exceeded.
val retrySchedule = Schedule.exponential(baseDelay) && Schedule.recurs(maxRetries)
val retriedLogic = logic.retry(retrySchedule)

// Then, repeat the whole retriedLogic infinitely.
val repeatSchedule = Schedule.spaced(1.second)
val wholeProcedure = retriedLogic.repeat(repeatSchedule)
```

As long as logic fails, it's retried with exponential backoff. But as soon as it succeeds, it's repeated in fixed intervals. If it fails again, exponential backoff starts again from `baseDelay`.

See a running example here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/yZpBO34NRgK6BgYYIzk5Iw

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!
It seems that my `logic.repeat().retry()` was the issue, while `logic.retry().repeat()` does what I need.